# change the background color of textview according to textview shape when click on text view

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-shapedrawable

I have three Material text views, I want to change the background color of the text view according to the text view shape. I tried multiple options but it goes outside of text view shape. I have round corners text view but color fill like a simple rectangle.

```
 <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLoseWeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:text="Lose Weight"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_500"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewGoals"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewLoseWeightSubtitle"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_outline_style"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="Get leaner and improve Your fitness"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_500"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewLoseWeight" />



 //.java
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.textViewLoseWeightSubtitle:
                        mLoseWgt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#363C60"));
                        mLoseWgt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

[image: This is the text view whose background and text color I want to change]

[image: After I click on it background color changes but goes outside of shape]

after clicking on the text view, it changes like above. I want background color inside  round corner shape like the original text view have

Comment: please add your XML layouts to get a better overview. Thanks

Comment: Assuming `mLoseWgt` is a `View`, Try setting `mLoseWgt.setClipToOutline(true)`

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your `TextView` and also it's `android:background` attribute:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Get leaner and improve Your fitness"
            android:background="@drawable/round_fill_color"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And here the mentioned attribute in a new `drawable` called `round_fill_color.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#363c60"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

That is the suggested way to make custom attributes for single `widgets`.

If you want to define one `layout` for all I recommend to do that over `styles.xml` and `themes`.

**The result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use something different:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
             ../>
```

and then apply a **`MaterialShapeDrawable`**

```
    val radius = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius)

    val shapeAppearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radius)
        .build()

    val shapeDrawable = MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel)
    shapeDrawable.fillColor = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.xxx)
    shapeDrawable.setStroke(2.0f, ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.xx));
    ViewCompat.setBackground(textView, shapeDrawable)
```

[image]

Use this `ShapeAppearanceModel` to have 50% rounded corners:

```
val shapeAppearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel()
    .toBuilder()
    .setAllCorners(RoundedCornerTreatment())
    .setAllCornerSizes(RelativeCornerSize(0.5f))
    .build()
```

[image]